# "I been" or "I’ve been"?

Tags: grammaticality, tenses, present-perfect, past-perfect

In the famous song Every Breath You Take by The Police, Sting sings:

> Since you've gone I been lost without a trace…

I admit that I am not some expert in English Grammar, but this "I been" sounds a little bit strange to me. Shouldn’t it be "I’ve been"? And consequently, the beginning of the sentence changed into "Since you’d gone…"?

Comment: Song lyrics are allowed leeway with respect to grammar. This is why analysis is off topic here.

Comment: U ever seen the new Iron Man movie, meh? Holy dixie cow, it big wasted my money, I no kid you.

Answer (score 3):

The whole premise of your question is wrong, since the lyrics of the song you mention go thusly (http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/police/everybreathyoutake.html):

> Since you've gone **I've** been lost without a trace.

"**I been**" is not Standard English, and you should avoid writing it outside of quoted direct speech.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I’m not absolutely sure, but I think that the lyrics are printed like that on the original record. Maybe I’m wrong.

Comment: In future, you might find that for any given song, typing "SONG NAME + lyrics" into Google is sufficient to give you a transcript of the song. It's also worth bearing in mind that songs are routinely ungrammatical and not representative of normal spoken/written English, so you should always be exceptionally wary of making grammatical generalizations from songs you've heard.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the words we have in mind when we speak and the way they those words sound to someone else's ear may be at variance. In the part of the United States where I live, it's very common for speakers to swallow the v sound in "I've been"; as a result, if you didn't know (or assume) that they intended to say "I've been," you might very well conclude that the actual words they spoke were "I been."

Comment: "Ungrammatical" is not. Every dialect of expression with a consistent pattern is "grammatical" unto its own. Perhaps, you meant to say "unusual", "abnormal" or "improper" grammar.

Comment: @BlessedGeek: I know of no dialect where "I been" is in common usage. Certainly in written texts "I been" is straightforwardly wrong because it would never be written by a native English speaker.

Comment: Thank you guys for explanation.
… and of course I know that I can find any song lyrics on internet, that’s what I actually did. I am also aware that not every song lyrics on internet are 100% correct. 
OK, anyway, I got the point.

Comment: Even pidgin English has consistent dialectical patterns, hence grammatical patterns. The English language began as a creole - would be a rather "ungrammatical" creole. To this day, the French seems to have been flabbergasted why this "ungrammatical" ill-formed creole (having unabashedly borrowed and then twisted words from their language) could have taken precedence over their "more romantic" language.

Comment: @Matt You've never listened to AAVE then, I suppose, or Southern US English. "I been" is common there and I use it in my writing as a demonstration of the dialect.

Comment: @KitFox: In which case, I retract my assertion that it is ungrammatical. Still, outside of quoted direct speech, one should generally avoid writing "I been", as it's certainly not "Standard English".